# Specifying a repo for a specific package in pip

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have a privately hosted package that has a name conflict with a public package found on PyPi. Unfortunately, because the public version is higher than my private package, a simple `pip install <package_x>` command finds the public version instead of my privately hosted package.

In effect:

```
PyPi (public) hosts package_x==1.5.0
PrivateRepo (private) hosts package_x==1.3.0
```

I would like `pip install package_x` to install the private version 1.3.0 without requiring me to specify the version or the index within the pip install command (purely through a configuration file.)

I'm trying to set up my pip config to look only at a specific private repo for a single package, but both the private repo and the standard `https://pypi.python.org/simple/` repo for everything else. I tried setting the private repo as my index-url and PyPi as an extra-index-url, but that will still search both repositories for the most recent package version.

Is there anyway to specify, within my pip config, the specific repo to use for a given package? Ideally something like this:

```
[global]
force-index: https://privaterepo.net/simple
    - package_x
```

Comment: Pipenv supports this, and I suspect Poetry does too. Are you married to `pip`, or are you willing to switch to a newer tool?

Comment: I am fairly married to pip, unfortunately. I'm trying to set this up in an enterprise environment in which dozens of engineers are going to be using pip. The goal is to simplify their lives as much as possible.

Comment: The ability to limit the searched repos for certain (private) packages will become vital in the very near future as demonstrated in [this article](https://medium.com/@alex.birsan/dependency-confusion-4a5d60fec610).

Comment: Using only configuration this can't be achieved. A writeup of the current state of package source selection can be found [here](https://github.com/ComputeCanada/software-stack/blob/main/pip-which-version.md). And this is the correlating issue on pip's own github repo: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10156

Answer (score 5):

If you're using **Pip** you can add `--extra-index-url` in the `requirements.txt` to specify additional repositories like this:

```
--extra-index-url=https://your-private-pypi-repo.com/simple
Flask==2.0.2
helloworld==0.1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Pip

Unfortunately pip does not allow this. The closest you come to something like this is to use the `--index-url` option in a `requirements.txt` file to use a different index, but this is a global option which means it overrides any other such options already defined, and it cannot be defined per package

There are other recent tools available which allows us to have granular control of python dependencies and their sources

#### Poetry

The first is [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/), which gives us this option within a `pyproject.toml` file.

From the [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#install-dependencies-from-a-private-repository)

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "foo"
url = "https://foo.bar/simple/"
secondary = true

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
requests = {version="*", source="foo"}
maya = {version="*", source="pypi"}
records = "*"
```

The above adds a new package repo called `foo` to your list of sources, but still keeps `pypi` as the primary source. *The docs also explains how to completely [ignore `pypi`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#disabling-the-pypi-repository) and use your private repo as the only source for packages.*

In the `tool.poetry.dependencies` section, we also specify three packages and where they should be installed from:

- `requests` installs from `foo`
- `maya` installs from `pypi`
- `records` installs by default from `pypi`

[Install](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#installing-dependencies-only) the dependencies with:

```
poetry install --no-root
```

*You can also use the `--source` option to the `poetry add requests` to specify which source to use*

#### Pipenv

You can use [Pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) to accomplish this.

From the [docs](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#specifying-package-indexes), add the following to your `Pipfile`:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[[source]]
url = "http://pypi.home.kennethreitz.org/simple"
verify_ssl = false
name = "home"

[dev-packages]

[packages]
requests = {version="*", index="home"}
maya = {version="*", index="pypi"}
records = "*"
```

The above, allows you to install `maya` from [`pypi`](https://pypi.org/), whereas `requests` will be installed from a custom/private package index.