# Use setuptools to Install a Python package from a private Gitlab package repository

Tags: python, setuptools, gitlab-api

I created a private package for my employer. Since I’m forbidden to upload it to PyPI (it’s proprietary), I uploaded it to the packages index for my project on our private Gitlab hub. I can install it manually with:

```
$ pip install my-package --extra-index-url https://__token__:my-token-xxx@gitlab.company-domain.com/api/v4/projects/123456/packages/pypi/simple
```

Now I also want [setuptools](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/) to be able to find it when listed in the install_requires argument to setup(). I tried:

```
setup(
  install_requires=[
    f"my-package @ https://__token__:{API_TOKEN}@gitlab.company-domain.com/api/v4/projects/123456/packages/pypi/simple",
    ...
    ],
  ...
```

`pip install -e .` results in

```
ERROR: HTTP error 404 while getting https://__token__:****@gitlab.company-domain.com/api/v4/projects/123456/packages/pypi/simple
```

This is different than

```
my-package @ git+https://user:password@gitlab.company-domain.com/..../my-package.git
```

That works, but I want to be able to download it as a pre-built wheel.

I’m not sure whether this is a setuptools issue or a Gitlab issue. The 404 response tells me that it might be a gitlab issue, yet the same URI works perfectly when used with the pip install CLI command.

This question is similar to [Include python packages from gitlab's package registry and other external indexes directly into setup.py dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65581442/270511), but I don't think that one got sufficient response. I posted the same question to [discuss.python.org](https://discuss.python.org/t/dependency-notation-including-the-index-url/5659/63?u=lsiden), but that discussion is old and I think I might get a quicker response here.

I also found [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68900614/270511) to a similar question, which wasn't encouraging. It recommends Poetry or Pipenv. I've tried both, and found each to be excruciatingly slow when resolving dependencies, so I fell back on setuptools.

Answer (score 2):

Only include the package name in `install_requires`. Then, configure your (extra) index URL in your pip configuration (either environment variables or `pip.conf`/`.pypirc` or CLI argument). Then using `pip install` as normal will work.

For example:

In `setup.py`:

```py
    # ...
    install_requires=[
        'my-package-name',
        # ...
    ],
    # ...
```

Then the install command (assuming the environment variable `API_TOKEN` exists):

```sh
GITLAB_INDEX="https://__token__:${API_TOKEN}@gitlab.company-domain.com/api/v4/projects/123456/packages/pypi/simple"
pip install --extra-index-url "${GITLAB_INDEX}" -e .
```

Comment: how to add it in .pypirc?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is do not use the "GitLab package registry" approach, but use simple the "repository level" approach:

```
dependencies = [
    "my-package @ git+https://deploy-token-name:deploy-token-value@git.my.domain/path-to-package-project/my-package.git",
]
```

You might generate `deploy-token` in repository setting.

This solution allows to bypass any deals with `extra-index-url`. And anyone in my team can install my package on any platform without an extra configuration of pip.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can just maintain your Python wheels in a directly like so: /path/to/simple/my-module. I don’t even bother to use twine to post new versions of my module. Instead, I use a simple bash script that makes sure that new wheel files are given read-only permissions so I can’t accidentally overwrite them without bumping the semver version number. With Docker and nginx, I set up a simple “autoindex” HTTP file server to the “simple” top-level-directory so I can access the wheels from other hosts if I want to. Finally, in my pip.conf, I have `extra-index-url=https://my-server:port/simple` and trusted-host=my-server.

I tried hosting my custom-built Python wheels in Gitlab and OneArtifactory. My company maintains instances of both. But I found that the access requirements and red-tape were too cumbersome, so I switched to my roll-your-own method, which I regret not having taken up much sooner.